# How can I lock out an account after a certain number of successful logins?

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, securid

I have a remote-access VPN, which is authenticated against a RSA SecurID server, and also against Active Directory.

For complicated internal policy reasons, someone has made a request that we are able to suspend access after a set number of logins per user.

For example, user john.doe can log in 100 times, but after that, his account will be disabled in AD until manually reinstated.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how and where best to configure this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would check if on active directory side this counts as a normal logon.
In that case what about powershell / vbs?
This is a path I'd go: http://blog.dabasinskas.net/count-number-of-users-who-logged-on-to-workstation-in-the-last-month-with-batch-script/

Comment: It will count as a normal logon, because it goes through a Citrix netscaler, and to a VDI instance, so the user has to login to the VDI desktop..

Comment: We need more informations, like the type of VPN you use (proprietary, open-source), the plateforms (Linux, Windows, embedded systems). Could be easy on Linux / OpenVPN / Pam using a probe on logs, but way harder on Microsoft Windows for example.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter what VPN we use, as the authentication all takes place on Active Directory, but fwiw, it's a Citrix Netscaler, providing a SSL VPN connection to Citrix XenDesktop.

Answer (score 1):

### Limiting Concurrent Logins

There is no built-in Microsoft method to limit concurrent user logins, sorry.  However, third party tools have come to the rescue for this. If you're on Server 2003 (shame on you), then the free [LimitLogin](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2005.05.utilityspotlight.aspx) tool might work. If you're on 2008 R2 and above, then have a look at [UserLock](http://www.isdecisions.com/products/userlock/).  It's not free, but does what you need.  Lastly, if you are on a budget you MAY be able to script out something.  There is an example [here](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Security-tools-that-limit-user-logon-in-Windows).

> For example, you could create a Windows login script component that maps a
>   drive to the user's home directory share. If it's unable to create the
>   mapping, then error out and log off. On each user's home directory
>   share, you would set the maximum number of connections to 1. When the
>   user logs in once, all's well. However, doing so twice would generate
>   a net use error level of 1. This error could be captured in the login
>   script to redirect to the logoff command and exit.

Also moire script examples [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/prevent-multiple-logons-gpos), and [here](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/53899-my-script-prevent-multiple-logins.html). Good luck!

### Limiting Total Logins

If - as @JacobEvans suggested - you are looking at Total number of logins instead of concurrency, then you can check the AD attribute [Logon-Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676845(v=vs.85).aspx).  The catch is, you'd have to sum the LogonCount from all DCs. I'd imagine you want to have a look [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/10/06/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-domain-controllers-in-my-domain-part-2/) for how to count DCs and combine the script here [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/02/17/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-times-a-user-has-logged-on-to-a-computer/) for how to count logons. An example.

```
Set objUser = GetObject _

    (“LDAP://atl-dc-01/cn=ken myer, ou=Finance, dc=fabrikam, dc=com”)

Wscript.Echo objUser.LogonCount
```

If scripting isn't your thing then paid-for tools like [ManageEngine](https://www.manageengine.com/windows-active-directory-tools.html) or the [Netwrix](https://www.netwrix.com/top_7_freeware_tools.html) suite of tools DO have reports that list the number of times a user has logged in.

Comment: I don't think he cares about concurrency

Comment: @JacobEvans Good point.  I've added a section about how to count the total number of logins.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a script, if corporate policy wants this, they can pay $$ for managed engine